# MKMapView in UITableViewCell is not reachable for user in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mkmapview

I'm embedding a MKMapView in a UITableViewCell which works quite well. Unfortunately, the map can not be used e.g. zoomed, scrolled or tapped. Even the legal link from Apple is not tappable.

Any advice is welcome.

```
let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "locationDetailMapCell")
            
let mapView = MKMapView()
            
mapView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 400)
mapView.mapType = .standard
mapView.showsUserLocation = true
mapView.isZoomEnabled = true
mapView.isScrollEnabled = true

mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(currentLocation.latitude), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(currentLocation.longitude)), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.02, longitudeDelta: 0.02)), animated: true)
            
let pin = MKPointAnnotation()
pin.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(currentLocation.latitude), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(currentLocation.longitude))
mapView.addAnnotation(pin)
            
cell.addSubview(mapView)
            
return cell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be adding the mapView to the cell's `contentView` rather than as a subview of the cell directly.

```
cell.contentView.addSubview(mapView)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an issue with multiple gesture-recogniser. Scrollview (TableView) and MKMapView.

Checkout  [gestureRecognizer(_:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/coordinating_multiple_gesture_recognizers/allowing_the_simultaneous_recognition_of_multiple_gestures)